# jQuery UI datepicker doesn't work in IE7

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Helllo everyone,

Here is the sample of the JS code I use

```
function() {
    if($(".datepicker")) {
        $(".datepicker").datepicker($.datepicker.regional['de']);
    }
}
```

but it just does not show the page in IE7 under Windows.

Any ideas what did I do wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

IT works for me i have used it as,

```
 <script>
       $("#start_date").datepicker($.datepicker.regional['de']);   //also works
       $("#start_date").datepicker('option', 'dateFormat', 'yy-mm-dd');
       $("#end_date").datepicker();
       $("#end_date").datepicker('option', 'dateFormat', 'yy-mm-dd')

 </script>


       <input type="text" id="start_date" name="start_date" title ="Start Date" />
       <input type="text" id="end_date" name="enddate" title ="enddate" />
```

Comment: hello Hulk. Thanks for your answer, but it does not help me in solving my problem. nope I did not down vote. I am not registered, therefor I can not vote...

Comment: <input type="text" class="datepicker required input" name="start_date" id="start_date"/>

Comment: Could u add this line and try,$(".datepicker").datepicker('option', 'dateFormat', 'yy-mm-dd'); IT worked for me with the same class too,add it after ur line.I faced a problem once likt this when i used to call the datepicker function at ready though i used to construct the textbox later from javascript

Comment: I've tried it already... I've even tried the most basic $(".datepicker").datepicker(); and I've tried with $("#start_date").datepicker(); but it just does not work. The thing is that on some computers Win, IE7 it does work (asked some colleagues to test it) and on most does not.

Comment: where u call the datepicker function inside ready or some other function.. html and so on..

Comment: the interesting thing is that it stills work by some computers that are running on Win/IE7...

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/ the thing is that now I see that THIS works on that same computer. So the problem is obviously not in the Datepicker itself.

Comment: Hmnn let me know how u resolved it.....or if u want any help.I replied to ur post bcoz i 2 was working on the same thing..By the way www.edmwiki.at/calendar/addevent asks for username/password.;) If u dnt mind what is the site about

Comment: Hmmm I've resolved it by figuring that there was nothing wrong with the Datepicker itself but with the HTML code it was nested in...

Comment: Thats the reason i asked for more code.May be accept the answer or little points for the effort ;)